# tabview implementation with activitygroup in which onKeyDown and list.setOnItemClickListener in child activity not work in Android

Tags: android

In my code I implement the tabview with activitygroup so that tab will be visible in my all nested view. But when I go to the nested view which contain listview. when I select item from the listview app crashed. And also app crashed on back button press.

```
 //Code of listview selection
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           int position, long id) 
       {

           String selectedFromList = (String) (list.getItemAtPosition(position));
            FourthGroup.group.back();

       }
     });
 //Code of back button

  @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
   {
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
           FourthGroup.group.back();
            return true;
        }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

below is logcat on listview item selection

```
   08-24 11:19:47.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.YouSaidIt.EditProfile
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at com.android.YouSaidIt.FourthGroup.back(FourthGroup.java:46)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at com.android.YouSaidIt.FilterCountry$1.onItemClick(FilterCountry.java:123)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3606)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1751)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   08-24 11:19:47.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should be using `list.getItemAtPosition(position)` . It returns the view AFAIK and not string. Instead use the position and then get the data from the cursor using this position.